# Computing the following integral: $\int_0^1 R^ke^{2 \pi i k n t} 2 \pi i n R e^{2 \pi i n t} dt.$

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to solve the following integral:
$\displaystyle{\int_{0}^{1}R^{k}\,\mathrm{e}^{2\pi\mathrm{i}knt}\,\,\,
2\pi\mathrm{i}nR\,\,\mathrm{e}^{2\pi\mathrm{i}nt}\,\,\mathrm{d}t}$.

My problem isn't computing the integral (for I get the same answer as the pHD student who solves the exercices for us) but there is one step in his computation I don't understand.

It goes as follows:

$\int_0^1 R^ke^{2 \pi i k n t} 2 \pi i n R e^{2 \pi i n t} dt.$

= $\int_0^1 R^{k+1}e^{2 \pi i (k+1) n t} 2 \pi i n$

= $[\dfrac{1}{k+1} R^{k+1} e^{2\pi i n (k+1) t}]_0^1   = (*)$

= 0

**My issue**:

I don't understand line $(*)$

Why isn't it $[\dfrac{R^{k+1}}{(k+1)2\pi i n} e^{2\pi i n (k+1) t}]_0^1 $?

Comment: Because you've already got a factor of $2\pi i n$ in the integral. Taking the antiderivative just cancels this factor.

Comment: The factor $2\pi in$ cancels the denominator $2\pi in$ as said by @Semiclassical.

Comment: Thank you I understand now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Why isn't it $[\dfrac{R^{k+1}}{(k+1)2\pi i n} e^{2\pi i n (k+1) t}]_0^1 $?*

One may recall that
$$
\int e^{\lambda t}dt= \frac{e^{\lambda t}}{\lambda},\quad \lambda \neq0,
$$ giving
$$
\lambda \times\int e^{\lambda t}dt= e^{\lambda t}.
$$